# How to solve the " Assertion '__pos <= size()' failed" in app which have to recognizes the sex after the name?

Tags: c++

Hi I learn c ++ acutally write a program that is to determine on the last letter in the Polish name, whether it is a female or male name. Fun fact: all of the female names in Polish ends with the letter "a".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std
int main()
{
   string imie;
    cout<<"Podaj imie: ";
    cin>> imie;

    int dlugosc=imie.length();

    if (imie[dlugosc-1]=='a'||'A')

        cout<<"Jestes kobieta";

    else cout<<"Jestes mezcyzna";

    return 0;
}
```

After entering this code, the application normally fires but, if you type a female or male name, this error pops up.

```
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1067: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference = char&; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]: Assertion '__pos <= size()' failed.
```

What should I change in this app to work properly?

Comment: `if (imie[dlugosc-1]=='a'||'A')` this doesnt do what you think it does (this is effectively `if (true)`) what you want is `if (imie[dlugosc-1]=='a'||imie[dlugosc-1]=='A')`

Comment: `if (imie[dlugosc-1]=='a'||'A')` -- I bet you have never seen an `if` statement that looks like this in the books and other material you are using to learn C++.  How are two or more conditions specified in an `if` statement?

Comment: There should  probably be a semicolon after `using namespace std`.

Comment: @grek643 What's the value of `dlugosc` when it hits that `assert()`?

Comment: @NathanMills — leaving out the semicolon was partly correct. Leaving out the rest of that line would have been fully correct. Don’t write `using namespace std;`.

Comment: please provide a [mre]. Is `imie` empty? You could also replace `imie[dlugosc-1]` with `imie.back()`

Comment: The assertion appears to be saying that `dlugosc-1` is greater than `imie.size()`. To prove the compiler wrong, you'll need to determine what those values are. Perhaps you could stream them to `std::cerr` right before your `if` statement?